# Multi theaded program sharing variables on NUMA system

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, pthreads, numa

I am doing some experiment with NUMA systems.Where in I have a multithread/2-threads c program sharing one cache line (int64) variable between them. When I run both threads on the same node the program takes nearly 50% more time to finish than if I run/bind these threads on two different NUMA nodes. I was thinking it should be other way round because  they share the data, they should finish faster if they run on the same node.

Am I missing something here?

```
  pthread_mutex_lock (&shared_mutex);
  if (thinfo->thread_num == 1)
    shared_var++;
  else
    shared_var--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&shared_mutex);
```

Comment: Update the code in the question. Avoid it in comments section

Comment: How many cores do you have per NUMA node? If there's only one core, then the contention for the CPU resource would easily explain why the two threads slow down, even though the memory resource is less contended. In that case, having the two threads on different nodes gives the program twice as much CPU bandwidth, even though the single cache line will bounce around a lot...

Comment: My system has 2 NUMA nodes with 6 cores each.